# How to get the last value of a string?

Tags: javascript

How can i control in java script, wheter the last character in a string is a ", " and how can i delete the last character, if it is a ", "?

```
var stringToControl = "ABC, XYZ, OOP, "
```

Comment: The last character looks like whitespace to me ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any whitespace between 'java' and 'script' either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (stringToControl.slice(-2) === ', ') {
  stringToControl = stringToControl.slice(0, -2);
}
```

`slice` method returns part of a string. First argument is the start position and optional second argument - the end position. If you don't pass second arguments, `slice` will return part from `start` argument to the end of the string. If you pass negative value, it means the position from the end (so `.slice(-2)` means 2 last characters).

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is an article on MDN

Another approach is to use RegExp:

```
stringToControl = stringToControl.replace(/, $/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

"Comma followed by any number of white space characters at the end of a string" can be expressed as a regular expression: `/,\s*$/`.

So to get rid of it you can replace it with an empty string:

```
stringToControl = stringToControl.replace(/,\s*$/,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

use slice

```
var temp = "abcd,aa,a,as,c,d, ".trim();
if(temp.endsWith(',')) 
temp = temp.slice(0,-1);
temp
```